# Does Symfony2 Dependency Injection support Object Lifestyle?

Tags: symfony, dependency-injection

I have a class which I load via dependency injection within Symfony 2.
It has a number of default private variables which I can override with setters.

Problem is, once one of those default values are set to something else within a page, there is no way to set it back automatically.
I don't want to call the class again using **new** as it removes the usefulness of the dependency injection.

So, does Symfony2 support Object LifeStyle, or do I basically need to write a public function which resets all of the defaults back to normal and call it each time it is required.

As an example, I use a class to get remote files. It has defaults for UserAgent, Accepted Language/Encoding, Method etc. But if I set the Method to POST, instead of the default GET for one call in a page, the next time I call it, it is still POST, where as I wish it to be the default GET once more, which it would be if I used **new** instead of via dependency injection.

Comment: Some possible solutions: don't use shared services (create a new instance every time); use scopes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add scope: prototype to your service definition.  This will ensure you get a new instance from the container each time you request your class.  And of course the instance will have the default values.

http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/service_container/scopes.html

Comment: Exactly what I needed! Thanks. I will add that I am using it under $container->register('x')->setScope() rather than $container->setDefinition('x')->setScope(). But still what I needed!

Comment: How do I set the scope of my class to prototype, without having to have all of the parent classes, controllers etc. to be prototype? It makes sense for the class I am interested in to be prototype, but not the things it is injected into. Currently, it comes up with ScopeCrossingInjectionException.

Comment: e.g. as it stands at the moment, any class or controller which use my get remote file class, has to be set to prototype, if my get remote file class is prototype.